# cmake: recursively collect all the linked shared libraries

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to write a function in cmake, that will recursively collect all the linked libraries (that are of type SHARED)?

This is a function that goes only one level deep, and appends `*-NOTFOUND` entities to the list, that I would like to avoid.

```
get_target_property(libs App LINK_LIBRARIES)
set(list_libs ${libs})
foreach(lib ${libs})
    get_target_property(ls ${lib} LINK_LIBRARIES)
    list(APPEND list_libs ${ls})
endforeach()

message(STATUS "Linked libraries: ${list_libs}")
```

If it is possible, that would make deployment rather trivial. Because we would have a definitive list of dlls that needs to be copied to the folder of the executable or dependent library.

```
foreach(lib ${list_libs})
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:${lib}> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:App>
endforeach()
```

Comment: Pretty straightforward in Bazel.build.  :-)

Comment: See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#get-runtime-dependencies

Comment: @sakra `Please note that this sub-command is not intended to be used in project mode.` If I just want to build a target and copy its dependencies to its folder, I doubt that this command would help me. If I understood correctly, this is to be used with an install command.